# Issue with ActiveRecord association: "The Lap model class is not an ActiveRecord::Base subclass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

I'm facing a strange issue with an ActiveRecord association in my Ruby on Rails project. When I try to access the `laps` association method from my `User` model, I get a peculiar error.

Error:

```
ArgumentError: The Lap model class for the User#laps association is not an ActiveRecord::Base subclass.
```

I've double-checked, and `Lap` is definitely a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base`. I'm using Rails 7.1.3 and Ruby 3.2.2.

Here's the code for my `User` model:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :laps
end
```

And here's the code for my `Lap` model:

```rb
class Lap < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue or have any ideas on how to resolve it?

I use

```rb
User.reflect_on_association(:laps).klass
```

what create an error
but with the relation quiz `has_many :laps` and `Quiz.reflect_on_association(:laps).klass`

There is no errors in the 2nd case so I didn't understand why to similar code have different résult.

Comment: What code is specifically giving you the error? Something like `User.last.laps`?

Comment: Did you add user_id in laps table?

Comment: Ok, I recently stumbled on the same problem, and from that I would guess you have some class in `User::Lap` namespace.
[Here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2017/03/why-you-should-not-use-a-class-as-a-namespace-in-rails-applications/) and [here](https://dev.to/jbranchaud/referencing-the-global-namespace-with-ruby-s-scope-resolution-operator-42mf) are some articles about this